# NSURL nil because of spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

The endpoint does not care if the URL has spaces in it, but `NSURL` seems to.

I get `nil` for `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];` every time:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://endpoint.com/search?one=%@&two=%@", textField1.text, textField2.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSString *urlAbsolute = [url absoluteString];
[theManager GET:urlAbsolute parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
```

I want to pass spaces into the endpoint because I want to get spaces out of the endpoint. (i.e. pass "Star Wars" in, so I get "Star Wars" back out instead of "StarWars" if I removed spaces from the string).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do some research on `NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`.

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried that, was going to put that in the notes, but can't seem to get it working even though I assume its possibly what I'm looking for.  I tried `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` but couldn't get it to work, and I'm not sure why?

Comment: You should update your question with your attempt to use that method.

Comment: BTW - what's the point of `url` and `urlAbsolute`? Why not just use `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the string encoding with allowed characters 
Please find the below code.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://endpoint.com/search?one=%@&two=%@", textField1.text, textField2.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: Don't apply `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` to the whole URL, just the parts that need it (the two values from the two text fields).

Comment: @rmaddy that tip is the key, I'd only ever seen the whole URL being encoded in my research.  Big big help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
NSString *firstArgument = [self.textField1.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSString *secondArgument = [self.textField2.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://endpoint.com/search?one=%@&two=%@", firstArgument, secondArgument];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSString *urlAbsolute = [url absoluteString];
```

Comment: Could someone explain me why is the down-voted answer ?

Comment: Because this answer is not how it should be done. This code first needlessly replaces just spaces in the two bits of text. What about all other possible characters that should be escaped? And then it improperly uses `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` on the whole URL.

Comment: @rmaddy about improperly uses of `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters ` you're completely right - it was my copy-paste mistake. I edited my answer, and right know should be OK I think.

Thank you for your vigilance